# Laravel 8 routing

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, laravel-8

I have a a function which gets all the data from the date inputted by the user and pass it to the table in view. In that table individual row of data retrieved from database  has one anchor tag which carries id of each row in database to update the column in the database. All works fine but i'm having problem in redirecting to the table after update. i'm getting problem due redirecting to the page maturity_reqController/'whatever_ids' which doesnot exists but dont khow how to fix it.

My anchor Tag goes

```
<a href="maturity_reqController/{{$items->id}}">Request</a>
```

My Route goes

```
Route::get('maturity_reqController/{id}', [SettlementController::class,'maturity_reqController']);
```

my Controller goes

```
function maturity_reqController($id){
        $forset = new Settlement();
        $forset->org_document_id = $id;
        $forset->save();

     $data = Doc::find($id);
     $data->status = "Maturity Requested";
     $data->save();
     return redirect('maturity_reqController');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a name to your route like so:

```
Route::get(
'maturity_reqController/{id}',
[SettlementController::class,'maturity_reqController']
)->name('maturity.req');
```

Then whenever you need to link to that route use

```
<a href="{{ route('maturity.req', ['id' => $items->id] }}">Request</a>
```

Edit: to redirect to that route:

```
return redirect()->route('maturity.req', ['id' => $items->id]);
```

More on [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes)

Comment: i tried to redirect to the table in controller by return redirect('maturity.req'); is says Page not found

Comment: I edited the answer to add the redirect part. You use `redirect()->route(...)` to redirect to a named route

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
return redirect()->back();
```

for more details : [laravel redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirects)

Answer (score 0):

**Your Link**

```
<a href="{{ route('maturity_req', ['id' => $items->id]) }}">Request</a>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('maturity_reqController/{id}', [SettlementController::class,'maturity_reqController'])->name('maturity_req');
```

**Controller**

```
function maturity_reqController($id) {
    $forset = new Settlement();
    $forset->org_document_id = $id;
    $forset->save();

    $data = Doc::find($id);
    $data->status = "Maturity Requested";
    $data->save();
    return redirect()->route('maturity_req', ['id' => 'Your ID'])->with('success', 'Your Message');
}
```